# Qt Creator -- how to disable "Update Documentation" process on startup

Tags: qt

What is the plugin or is there some other way to disable this automated documentation update?  It takes a very long time (in internet seconds) to accomplish or to time out.  I have taken to leaving Qt Creator open at all times to avoid it.  When one runs a PC disconnected from the internet, this is particularly annoying.  Data plan limitations also are a reason to only use this on demand and not automatically.

Comment: The "Update Documentation" task is local & very fast, in all my machines, and can't be disabled. What may be long and requires network is "Checking for Updates". You may disable this one in Options->Environment->Update->[x] Automatic Check for Updates.

Comment: It is not "fast" at all if you are not internet connected because it apparently involves a timeout instead of verifying that there is in fact an internet connection before trying.  

It is not "fast" if connected for that matter.  You may have Gigabit connectivity, but we in the rural areas do not have that luxury.

Comment: I've disconnected just now the Ethernet cable in a windows laptop (with disabled wifi as well) and started QtCreator 4.10.2; the "Update documentation" progress in the lower right corner lasts for less than a second, and after that QtCreator works normally without Internet connection. Your installation may be corrupted.

Comment: This is 4.9.2.  Hopefully, they have remedied my observed behavior then! Thanks for the test.

Comment: 4.10.2 still does the same thing when disconnected from the internet.  There is apparently no distinction between an internet connection and a simple LAN connection.  I have a local LAN with no internet access for hardware testing.

Comment: Qt Creator went white on me for a full 2 minutes before giving up on the docs update.

At a minimum, the "feature" should be able to be manually triggered, otherwise disabled in user config.  If an automation MUST be done, at least check for the existence of internet before beginning a timed wait for it to finish.  ICK!

Comment: QtCreator must have been updated to "fix" this behavior.